# how to use for(int i = 10; i >= 5; ++i) {

Tags: java

for a school project, I am supposed to produce this output

```
10
1020
102030
10203040
1020304050
```

the code I currently have is this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rows = 5;
 
        for(int i = 10; I <= 5; ++i) {
            for(int j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
                System.out.print((i * j) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

but with this line like this it does nothing:

```
for(int i = 10; I <= 5; ++i) {
```

and like this it goes on indefinitely

```
for(int i = 10; I >= 5; ++i) {

with this output:

10
1011
101112

and so on forever.
```

I am thoroughly confused

Comment: Put the `i` in lower case. Also your end condition into the loop is lower than the start.

Comment: For starters, Java is case-sensitive so `for(int i = 10; I <= 5; ++i)` cannot compile (`i` and `I` are different variables.  Please show us the actual code, i.e. copy/paste, do not type it in.  Second, have you stepped through the code in the debugger?   Tell us what you found.  I suggest you take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: If starts at `10` and the loop goes while it is greater then `5` it runs indefinitely because it walways be greater

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions should not be overwritten by an edit, especially if an answer already exists. Also, there is a reason for those rate limits.

Comment: how do you close a question then?

Comment: i += 10 should be the increment of the for-loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A for loop has three parts, separated by semicolons:

1. **Initialization** - this runs at the beginning of the loop, before anything else
2. **Exit condition** - this is checked before each iteration of the loop. If it's `false`, then the loop breaks.
3. **Increment** - this operation happens at the end of each iteration. Usually, we use this to change a variable that we use in the exit condition.

Examining the loop `for(int i = 10; i <= 5; ++i)` which you present in your question, we can see:

1. The initialization is `int i = 10`, creating an integer `i` and assigning it the value `10`.
2. The exit condition is `i <= 5`. The loop will terminate as soon as the exit condition is false.
3. The increment is `++i`, which is functionally identical to `i = i + 1`. In other words, we're increasing `i` by one.

We can see, then, that the exit condition will fail immediately (10 is greater than 5), so the loop will be skipped.

Your other example, with an exit condition of `i >= 5`, will repeat indefinitely, because 10 is greater than 5 and that will continue to be true as you increase `10`.

---

The solution to your problem, as I understand it, is:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print(10 * j);
    }
    System.out.println() 
}
```

Here, we use `i` to count each line. For every line, we make a variable `j` to count the number of things to print on that line (one thing the first line, two things the second line, etc.).

Since the 'thing' we need to print is multiples of tens, we do `System.out.print(10 * j)`. This prints `10` on the first line, `10` then `20` on the second line, etc.

Comment: Upvoted.  It's at times like this that I wish I had a five upvote card to play, as I'm pretty sure this is the only upvote you will receive. `#reverse-psychology`

Comment: `i >= 5` will not  "repeat indefinitely", as you wrote. It will run until `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and then continue with `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the upper case typo (java is case sensitive), your loop start with value 10 and has to stop with value 5, so, it will never do nothing.

This is the first problem, also, the behaviour inside the loop is not ok, and it seems you don't know so well what is doing.

Think about you have tou show: Values from 1 to 5 where in the first line only one value is output, in the second line 2 values are output... and so on.

So, you need to loop for every "line", that is, your first loop have to be from 1 to 5:

```java
for(int i = 1; i <= rows; ++i) {
}
```

Then, for every line you want to output as values as line is. Then another loop. For 1 to "line" number. Knowing that the line is referenced by variable `i` then:

```java
for(int j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
}
```

And, what show into console? The value for each line * 10. Each value is stored in `j` variable.

```java
System.out.print(j*10);
```

And all together:

```java
int rows = 5;
for(int i = 1; i <= rows; ++i) {
    for(int j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
        System.out.print(j*10);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

I hope with this you can uderstand how loop works and how to implements in java.

I think the most important thing is understan what is happening in every iteration into the loop. You can write `System.out.print("i = "+i+" ; j = "+j);` to check the values in each iteration or use the debugger.